# C# CompareTo method confusion

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand the CompareTo method in C#. I understood that if the both variables are the same I get 0. But the part with the +1 and -1 confuses me a bit... Can someone explain it to me a bit more intuitively? (And yes I read the documentation)

Comment: The documentation explains what the numbers mean, so, given that you've already read it, what are you expecting us to tell you that it doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto), so it's hard to guess *what* confuses you.

`a.CompareTo(b)` should return

- -1 if `a` is less than `b`
- 0 if `a` is equal to `b` and
- 1 if `a` is greater than `b`

Maybe some examples can help:

```
5.CompareTo(10) // => -1, because 5 < 10
5.CompareTo(5) // => 0, because 5 == 5
5.CompareTo(3) // => 1, because 5 > 3
```

I said "should return", because the semantics of what "less", "equal" and "greater" mean depends on the specific type and it's implementation of `CompareTo`. The return values are a convention and when you implement your own `CompareTo` you should apply them to not confuse customers of your type.

Comment: The number comparing example made it clear now :) +1

Comment: One last question... I am comparing "A" and "a"    string A = "A";
            string a = "a";
            Console.WriteLine(A.CompareTo(a)); ... It returns 1, shouldn't it return -1 since the Unicode "A" has a lower value than "a" ?

Comment: @MitkoZ `string` makes a culture-specific lexical comparison. If you have a `List<string>` and call `.Sort()` on it, strings starting with lower-case characters come first. _Why_ it is implemented like that I don't know. But it's a _lexical_ sort, not by unicode or ascii value.

Comment: On the subject of the documentation, it only guarantees that "this precedes that" is indicated by a negative integer and "this follows that" is indicated by a positive integer, though, in practice, there's a good chance that checking for `-1` and `1`, specifically, will produce the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

CompareTo is a common name of multiple different methods, depending on the data type being compared. Thus, <0 and >0 results can mean slightly different things depending on context. Usually, <0 means that the instance is less than the compared object or precedes it in a list. >0 would mean greater than the compared object or follows it in a list.

Answer (score 0):

> Compares the current instance with another object of the same type and
>   returns an integer that indicates whether the current instance
>   precedes, follows, or occurs in the same position in the sort order as
>   the other object.

- -1 : The instances precedes object in the sort order.
- 0  : The instance occurs in the same position, or is considered a match.
- 1  : The instance follows object in the sort order.

Example:

```
A.CompareTo(A); // Must return zero.
A.CompareTo(B) // Returns a value other than zero, then B.CompareTo(A) should return the opposite.
A.CompareTo(B) // If returns a value x not equal to zero, and B.CompareTo(C) returns a value y of the same sign as x, then A.CompareTo(C) must return the value of the same as x and y.
```

All from the official documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If you mark it down, you should state why.  Also note, that you marked down official msdn documentation.

Comment: The documentation, though, does not state it will return `-1` and `1`, only negative and positive integers (which, when implemented, will likely be `-1` and `1`).