# Confusion with c# compareTo strings

Tags: python, c#

I have to convert c# component into python. I have problem with understanding compareTo method. I already saw examples for comparing numbers and that is clear. But I can not understand how to compare strings.

I have this code.

```
string s2 = "hellp";    
string s3 = "hello"; 
Console.WriteLine(s2.CompareTo(s3)); result of this is 1
Console.WriteLine(s3.CompareTo(s2)); result of this is -1
```

Why am I getting different results? In `s2.CompareTo(s3)` the result is 1, and in `s3.CompareTo(s2)` the result is -1.

And how to write this `s2.CompareTo(s3)` into python?

Comment: comparing means greater equal less. You want equality, not comparasion

Comment: Yes, but I have in my C# component ```if (Value.Substring(0, 4).CompareTo("1888") > 0) return false;```. What this mean? @DownloadPizza 
 thank you for help

Comment: It checks if the substring appears first in whatever the default sorting for strings is (im guessing alphabetically). Refer to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=net-6.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# CompareTo method confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492054/c-sharp-compareto-method-confusion)

Comment: One question per post please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you test for equality of strings, you should use the methods that explicitly specify what kind of comparison you intend to perform. You specify which type of comparison to perform. Avoid using the == and != operators when you test for equality. String.CompareTo instance methods always perform an ordinal case-sensitive comparison. They are primarily suited for ordering strings alphabetically.

The test for equality with `String.Equals` and the `==` and `!=` operators differs from string comparison using the `String.CompareTo` and `Compare(String, String)` methods. They all perform a case-sensitive comparison. However, while the tests for equality perform an ordinal comparison, the CompareTo and Compare methods perform a culture-aware linguistic comparison using the current culture.

Comment: "_String.CompareTo instance methods always perform an ordinal case-sensitive comparison_" vs. "_the CompareTo and Compare methods perform a culture-aware linguistic comparison_" Fight! I bet on the second to win this fight... ;-)